# Firebase web client and OIDC Provider issues

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-identity-toolkit

I have configured an OIDC provider (linked to a Keycloak OIDC provider) in Google Identity Platform console. This is the code in my single page app:

```
provider = new firebase.auth.OAuthProvider('oidc.keycloak');
firebaseAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(provider)
      .then(value => {
        log.info(`It worked!`, value);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        log.info('Something went wrong:', err);
      });
```

The popup window appears and I can login to Keycloak, but after the popup disappears the following error is thrown in the browser:

```
{code: "auth/admin-restricted-operation", message: "This operation is restricted to administrators only."}
```

I am using the latest versions of Firebase Client SDK and AngularFire2 and I have successfully configured Email/Password authentication.
In Google Identity Platform I have:

Issuer (URL):

```
https://auth.example.com/auth/realms/myrealm
```

and 
Callback URL:

```
https://myapp-12345.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler
```

Is there an additional configuration in the client side that I need to do? Could the issue be with the OIDC provider (Keycloak) and its configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you disabled user signup from the client SDK in your Google Cloud Identity Platform settings (in the Google Cloud Console). This is in the `Settings` section under `User actions`. The checkbox `Enable create (sign-up)` should be checked.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Am I right in thinking this enables the public to sign-up to my application and there is no way of limiting sign-up only to users of a specific provider?

Comment: This setting is useful in case you do not want users to create their own account but only want a user to be created by an admin (via cloud console or admin sdk). This is typical for enterprise. You don't want employees to create their own account.

Comment: Understood. I have two kinds of users: those who sign-up via their organisation (OIDC and SAML) and those who login with their email/password. I don't want to allow sign-up for the latter, but sign-up has to be enabled for all otherwise the first group can't sign-in.

Comment: I see. That makes sense. Currently I think you cannot do a combination of both. Try to file a feature request for this: https://cloud.google.com/support-hub/ or via [firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/).

Comment: Another option is to upload your SAML and OIDC users to your Auth project ahead of time. Is this a feasible option?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I was thinking maybe I could ask the SAML users to sign-up via another link that is backed by the Admin SDK for the first time and then sign-up for the Client SDK can be disabled, but it is too much work for something that is supposed to be out-sourced.

Comment: I did file a feature request via Firebase support by the way.

Comment: i just enable the login for **anonymous user**. it worked for me